# Linear Algebra (question about linear independence).

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ and an $n \times m$ matrix (with $n \neq m$) such that $AB = I_m$.
*(We say that $A$ is a left inverse of $B$)*

- Are the columns of $B$ linearly independent?
- What about the columns of $A$?

I have no idea how to approach this question.
Please help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

> $$\ker(B)\subseteq \ker(AB)$$

Proof: Let $x\in \ker(B)$.  Then $Bx=0$.  This implies that $(AB)x=A(Bx)=A0=0$ and so $x\in \ker(AB)$.

---

- What do you know about $\ker(AB)$?
- What do you know about the relationship between a kernel and the linear independence of columns?
- Which do you think is the case? $n>m$ or $m>n$?  Are either possible?  What does the rank-nullity theorem have to say about this and what does this imply about $A$?

Answer (score 1):

If $\def\rk{\operatorname{rank}}\rk A$ denotes the rank of the $m\times n$ matrix $A$, we have $\rk A\le m$ and $\rk A\le n$.

Also the rank of a matrix product is less than or equal to the ranks of the factors.

The columns of $B$ are linearly independent if and only if $\rk B=m$. On the other hand, $I_m$ has rank $m$, so we have
$$
m=\rk I_m=\rk(AB)\le\rk B\le m
$$
Then…

Next, can $\rk A=n$?